# Linux Mint 19.1, white text on white background

Tags: gtk, gtk3, linux-mint, gtk2, cinnamon

I am having some problems with Linux Mint 19.1 (cinnamon edition), which shows some texts in white on white backgrounds.

This issue happens for example in the logs of gnome-builder or in the selected items in gnome-boxes:
[image: gnome-builder]
[image: gnome-boxes]

Answer (score 0):

Using a dark theme (currently using 'Vivaldi') "fixes" the issue